# Displaying separately the segment of the individual textures of a cube-map being rendered in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I have a cube map set up and what I want to do next is to mark/show separately which areas/segments of the textures on each face of the cube map is being rendered (depending on the camera).

For example, here is my basic vertex shader:

```
#version 400
in vec3 vp;
uniform mat4 P, V;
out vec3 texcoords;
vec3 newP;
void main () {
    texcoords = vp;
    gl_Position = P * V * vec4 (vp, 1.0);
}
```

and here is my basic fragment shader:

```
#version 400

in vec3 texcoords;
uniform samplerCube cube_texture;
out vec4 frag_colour;

void main () {
  frag_colour = texture (cube_texture, texcoords);
}
```

I now want to show the unfolded 6 textures of a cubemap and color overlay the areas the camera was looking at in the cube-map, for each texture.

Example, if my camera is viewing the intersection of the left and back sides of the cube, I want a separate display where the I can see the 6 side textures unfolded and the area of the respective textures, the camera was viewing, highlighted (half of the loaded texture for the left wall and half of the loaded texture for the back wall)

Can I get some heads up on how to implement this? Or if someone has some similar code in OpenGl.
Thanks :)

Comment: My reading of your question is that you want to show, for a given cube texture coordinate, which face *would* be used when fetching a cubemap. Is that correct?

Comment: not just which face, but also what area of the texture loaded on the face is being rendered

Comment: How do you want that information presented? A list of texels in the cubemap that were rendered to the screen? A particular color shown? Alterations to the cubemap itself, changing the value of colors that were fetched? It is not clear what you want to *see happen*.

Comment: show the unfolded 6 textures of a cubemap and color overlay the areas the camera was looking at in the cube-map, for each texture ..

Comment: Then put that *in your question*. Make your question more clear.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?